# beautifulsoup: find elements after certain element, not necessarily siblings or children

Tags: beautifulsoup

Example html:

```html
<div>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
    <p>p3<span id="target">starting from here</span></p>
    <p>p4</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>p5</p>
    <p>p6</p>
</div>
<p>p7</p>
```

I want to search for `<p>`s but only if its position is after `span#target`.

It should return p4, p5, p6 and p7 in the above example.

I tried to get all `<p>`s first then filter, but then I don't know how do I judge if an element is after `span#target` or not, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using the [`find_all_next`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) function in beautifulsoup.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = # Read the HTML here

# Parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')

# Select the first element you want to use as the reference
span = soup.select("span#target")[0]

# Find all elements after the `span` element that have the tag - p
print(span.find_all_next("p"))
```

The above snippet will result in

```html
[<p>p4</p>, <p>p5</p>, <p>p6</p>, <p>p7</p>]
```

Edit: As per the request to compare position below by OP-

If you want to compare position of 2 elements, you'll have to rely on [`sourceline` and `sourcepos`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#line-numbers) provided by the `html.parser` and `html5lib` parsing options.

First off, store the `sourceline` and/or `sourcepos` of your reference element in a variable.

```py
span_srcline = span.sourceline
span_srcpos = span.sourcepos
```

(you don't actually have to store them though, you can just do `span.sourcepos` directly as long as you have the `span` stored)

Now iterate through the result of `find_all_next` and compare the values-

```py
for tag in span.find_all_next("p"):
    print(f'line diff: {tag.sourceline - span_srcline}, pos diff: {tag.sourcepos - span_srcpos}, tag: {tag}')
```

You're most likely interested in line numbers though, as the `sourcepos` denotes the position *on a line*.

However, `sourceline` and `sourcepos` mean slightly different things for each parser. Check the docs for that info

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to use CSS selector instead but in the same range (after `#target`)?

Comment: Also, what if we want to search *between* two elements? All in all, if there is a way to decide the position of two elements (like `compareDocumentPosition` in JS), it would be very helpful.

Comment: @fireattack You can do that, with a bit of hackery, added the answer

Comment: I also didn't notice your other question, what do you mean "Is there a way to use CSS selector instead but in the same range". If you'd like to use css selectors for this, you'll be limited to only sibling elements, look into [global siblings combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

Comment: Explaining the css one is way beyond the scope of this question though and SO is not a discussion forum, so I hope my answer satisfies your needs for this particular question.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking if there is an easy way to search between two elements (but using css selector syntax instead of the one for `find` or `find_all_next`). But like you said, that's beyond the scope of this question. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
html_doc = """

<div>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
    <p>p3<span id="target">starting from here</span></p>
    <p>p4</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>p5</p>
    <p>p6</p>
</div>
<p>p7</p>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find(id="target").findNext('p').contents[0])
```

Result

```
p4
```

Answer (score 0):

*try*

```
span = soup.select("span > #target > p")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.